# Inline Block Elements Overflowing Parent Container

Tags: html, css

I have a list of 4 menu items sitting side by side using display:inline-block;. Each item is 120px, therefore I should be able to set the parent container to be 480px wide, however this sends the last item into the next row, why is this ??

Here is a jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/htdgdhxn/

My html:

```
<section id="nav">

    <div id="nav-wrapper">

        <ul id="nav-list">
            <li id="nav-home"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-clothes"><a class="category All">Clothes</a>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-about"><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li id="nav-contact"><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
            </li>                                                                           
        </ul>           

    </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#nav { background-color: #fff; }
#nav-wrapper { text-align: center; height: 74px; }
#nav-list { height: 100%; width: 480px; }
#nav-list li { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 120px; height: 100%; }
#nav-list li a { text-decoration: none; color: #000; font-size: 1.6em; display: block; height: 100%; line-height: 74px; }
#nav-list li a:hover { background-color: #F0ECE1; cursor: pointer; }
```

I have tested and this happens in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Comment: Are you having the padding or margin in your outer container?

Comment: No, as you can see in the jsFiddle and in my css I set the margin and paddings of everything to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the whitespace between each `<li>`

```
<li></li> <...space here...> <li></li>
```

Inline block elements create a gap between li elements.

```
<ul id="nav-list">
   <li id="nav-home"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
   </li><li id="nav-clothes"><a class="category All">Clothes</a>
   </li><li id="nav-about"><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
   </li><li id="nav-contact"><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
   </li>                                                                            
</ul>
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/htdgdhxn/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the width of your container to 500px

```
#nav-list { height: 100%; width: 500px; }
```

or remove the white spaces between consecutive li tags

or

apply `display:initial` in `#nav-list { height: 100%; width: 480px;}`

i.e `#nav-list { height: 100%; width: 480px; display: initial;}`

Comment: I could do this, but I want to know why 4 items with a width of 120px that together is 480px wide, does not fit into a container of that same size.

Comment: there was white space between our li items that @anpsmn mentioned in his answer.width of the space would be somewhere between 2 to 3 px so it got overflowed

Answer (score 1):

The inline-block value is incredibly useful when wanting to control margin and padding on
"inline" elements without the need to `block and float` them.One problem that arrises
when you use inline-block is that whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen.
Gross.There are a few ways to remove that space; some of them are just as gross, one is 
reasonably nicer.

**Solution 0: No Space Between Elements**:
The only 100% solution to this issue is to not put whitespace between those elements in the HTML source code:

```
<ul><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li><li>Item content</li></ul>
```

**Solution 1:  font-size: 0 on Parent**
The best white-space solution is to set a font-size of 0 on the parent to the inline block 
elements.

```
.inline-block-list { /* ul or ol with this class */
    font-size: 0;
}

.inline-block-list li {
    font-size: 14px; /* put the font-size back */
}
```

**Solution 2:  HTML Comments**
This solution is a bit gangsta but also works.  Using HTML comments as spacers between the elements works just as placing no space between elements would:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li><!--
 --><li>Item content</li>
</ul>
```

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Reason:-
1. The font size of the text in the li element might be causing the problem.
   You can modify it by reducing the font-size.

```
#nav-list li a { text-decoration: none; color: #000; font-size: 1.2em; display: block; height: 100%;line-height: 74px; }
```

2. Instead of using this

   ```
    #nav-list li { display: inline-block; }
   ```

You can do like this:-

```
     #nav-list li { display: inline; font-weight:bold;}
```

Please let me know if this helps.